# Get keysym for key char

Tags: python, xlib

I'm trying to implement global hotkeys in my application. I've got hooking and I've got the support for windows, so I just need to get some linux specific parts together. What I need is a way to get the key code/key sym for a specific key, something along the lines of key_ids["VK_A"] or key_ids["VK_LCTRL"].

I'm using Xlib and a record callback to get keyboard events.